# What's group $E(2)$ of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove normal subgroups of the group $E(2)$, but I haven't been given, what the group $E(2)$ of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is like.

What is it like?

Comment: In general: $${\rm E}(n) = \{ T \circ A \mid A \in {\rm O}(n) \text{ and }T \text{ is a translation}\}.$$

Comment: @IvoTerek What's $O(n)$?

Comment: It is the group of *orthogonal* matrices: the ones satisfying $AA^T = {\rm Id}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isometry group $E(n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the following matrix group
$$
E(n)={\rm Isom} ( \mathbb{R}^n) =\left\{\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
                \mid A\in O_n(\mathbb{R}), v\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}.
$$
The multiplication is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B & w \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=
 \begin{pmatrix} AB & Aw+v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
A normal subgroup consists of translations, given by
$$
T(n)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} I_n & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
                \mid  v\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}.
$$