# Group of translations is a normal subgroup of group $E(2)$ of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to see that:

The group of translations $T=\{t(x)=x+a : a \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$ is a normal subgroup of group $E(2)$ of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know the definitions of a normal subgroup, but I don't understand how the translations and isometries interact in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the notations of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773113/whats-group-e2-of-isometries-of-mathbbr2/1773241#1773241): The subgroup of translations in 
$$
E(n)={\rm Isom} ( \mathbb{R}^n) =\left\{\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
                \mid A\in O_n(\mathbb{R}), v\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\},
$$
given by
$$
T(n)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} I_n & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
                \mid  v\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}.
$$
is indeed normal. To see this, we compute
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} I_n & w \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} ^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix} I_n & Aw \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which is again in $T(n)$. Hence $T(n)$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Another way to phrase essentially the same argument: The function from $E(n)$ to $O_n(\mathbb R)$ that sends $\begin{pmatrix}A&v\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ to $A$ is a homomorphism, and the translations form its kernel.

Comment: Could you clarify why your definition of $T(n)$ is equivalent to mine.

Comment: Identify $x$ with $(x,1)$ and let $A$ be a matrix in $T(n)$. Then $Ax=(Ix+v,1)=(x+v,1)$, which is identified with $x+v$. So it is the same map as your $t(x)=x+v$.